# Date validation in AngularJs, when deleting the data and clicking submit

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html, datepicker

I have a date picker control in which I have added a required field validator. The error message shows correctly, if i do a backspace in the field and thereby remove the date and then click submit. But, If i select the date, and click on delete in keyboard and then click on submit button, the error message is not showing. 
Below is the existing code:

**Index.cshtml**

```
<div ng-controller="testController" ng-init="init()">
    <form name="mainForm" id="createForm" ng-submit="mainForm.$valid && add()" novalidate="">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label class="control-label">Start date</label>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group date" id="startDatepicker">
                    <input type="text" required="" class="form-control" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" ng-model="defaultStartDate" name="startDate">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <span style="color:red" ng-show="submitted == true && mainForm.startDate.$error.required">Start Date is required</span>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="submitted=true" />
    </form>
</div>
```

In the **controller.js**, date is set as below:

```
 var setDefaultDate = new Date();
    $scope.defaultStartDate = moment(setDefaultDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY');


    jQuery('#startDatepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
        defaultDate: new Date()
    });

    jQuery('#startDatepicker').data("DateTimePicker").minDate($scope.defaultStartDate);


    jQuery("#startDatepicker").on("dp.change", function(e) {
        jQuery('#startDatepicker').focus();     
    });
```

How to set the validation ?

Comment: why are you using jQuery date picker? instead try this out. https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker

Comment: Hi. This is a existing work, and i cannot make changes to the picker. Any reasons this date validation is not working? How to fix this?